# Does this inequality for sums hold for integrals too?

Tags: integral-inequality, holder-inequality

Let $f,g:I \to \mathbb R$ be positive functions on a finite set, then
$$
\left(\sum_i f(i)\right)\left(\sum_i g(i)\right) \geq \sum_i f(i)g(i)
$$
The proof is rather trivial: by multiplying out the sums, you can write the LHS as $\sum_i f(i)g(i) +$ crossterms, which are positive by assumption.
But when $f,g$ are (still positive) functions $X \to \mathbb R$ from a measure space $X$ then I can't find a reference for it:
$$
\left(\int_x f(x)dx\right)\left(\int_x g(x)dx\right) \geq \int_x f(x)g(x)dx
$$
This looks like an Holder-type inequality $\|f\|_1\|g\|_1 \geq \|fg\|_1$.
Can I use Fubini to conclude $\left(\int_x f(x)dx\right)\left(\int_x g(x)dx\right) = \int_{x,y}f(x)g(y)dxdy$ and then reason like above? Or can you suggest a different argument?

Answer (score 1):

It is false. If $f=g=1_E$ the inequality says $\lambda (E)^{2} \ge \lambda (E)$ (where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure). This is true only if $\lambda (E) \ge 1$.

Comment: Uhm good catch... So it holds if I add the assumption $\int f, \int g \geq 1$?

Comment: No. $f(x)=g(x)=e^{x}1_{(0, \ln 3)}$ is  a counter-example.  You just cannot expect any such inequality for integrals.  @seldon

Comment: It does hold for integrals over finite sets with their counting measure, so there should be some set of assumptions that make it work. How did you find that counterexample?

Comment: There are special cases where you get even equality. If $f$ and $g$ are independent random variables on $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure the equality holds. @seldon